# Forgot password for my cisco E1000 router

Tags: router

I have my Wi-Fi router (a Cisco E1000) hooked to my DSL router, and I forgot the password. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to reset the router to go back to factory defaults. You can press and hold the reset button on the backside for 5 seconds to return it to factory settings.